# Is there a TypeScript compiler option to force type checks on object properties?

Tags: typescript, typing

In order to write more robust code, I'm looking at using TypeScript for my web based projects.  I have relatively little experience with the language thus far, but I have run into a problem that I'm having difficulty searching for.

Consider the TypeScript code below:

```
public static getResponseCode(resObj: object): number {
    let c: number = resObj["c"]
    return c;
}
```

Is there a way that I can force the TypeScript compiler to pull me up here and tell me that `resObj["c"]` may not be a number and that I need to first check if it is a number?  E.g. can I force TypeScript to make me rewrite the code as this (or something similar)?:

```
public static getResponseCode(resObj: object): number {
    if (typeof resObj["c"] !== "number") { return APIResponseCode.UnknownFailure; }

    let c: number = resObj["c"]
    return c;
}
```

I expect I'm getting the results that I am simply because the type of `resObj["c"]` is `any`.  What can I do here?  Is there a common pattern used in TypeScript?

Comment: Use `resObj.c` instead of `resObj["c"]` to get type-checking on the property `c`.

Comment: Type `object` does not have a property `c`. @torazaburo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn on the `noImplicitAny` compiler option. The compiler will then complain any time something is implicitly any.

We set noImplictAny inside `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }
}
```

Or we set it like this `tsc --noImplicitAny` from the command line.

That would force you to do something.

For instance, you could use any explicitly.

```
public static getResponseCode(resObj: object): number {
    const resAny = resObj as any;
    if (resAny.c && typeof resAny.c !== "number") {
        return APIResponseCode.UnknownFailure;
    }

    const c: number = resAny.c;
    return c;
}
```

Or you could use an interface with [a union type and a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```
interface ResObj {
    c: boolean | string | number | object;
}

public static getResponseCode2(resObj: ResObj): number {

    if (typeof resObj.c !== "number") {
        return APIResponseCode.UnknownFailure;
    }

    const c: number = resObj.c;
    return c;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be exactly what I want.  Thanks very much.  Can you advise on whether or not I should be using the `object` type to pass in the result of a call to `JSON.parse`?  Or should I be using `any`?

Comment: I'm using TypeScript to generate client-side Javascript.  All requests/responses to and from my API are sent through jQuery AJAX as traditional javascript JSON objects.  What I'm asking is, does it make more sense for me to use the `object` type when passing these request and response objects around, or to use the `any` type?  I cannot make interfaces for all possible requests and responses, as they vary largely.  What would you suggest?

Comment: @LukePark `JSON.parse()` returns an `object` so I would use `object` instead of `any`, because `any` can also be a primitive such as `boolean`, which `JSON.parse()` would never return.

Comment: What about when I'm constructing a request object?  If I do something like `reqObj.t = "asd";` then I get "Property 't' does not exist on type object..." etc.

Comment: It depends on whether you want the compiler to help you or not. If you are going to use `any`, then the compiler is going to stop helping you, because `any` opts you out of static type checking. So, the choice between `any` or `object` (or some other type) is a trade off. We need to choose between the ease of developing with a dynamic language vs the safety of developing with a typed language.

Comment: Sounds like I want ease of development while sending and safety of a typed language when receiving... *sigh*, I always end up in situations like this.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript does no run-time type-checking. Depending on what you are trying to do, you have a couple of options. The first is to define an interface for `resObj`:

```
interface ResObj { c: number; }
```

Now

```
public static getResponseCode(resObj: ResObj): number {
  let c: number = resObj.c;
  return c;
}
```

Your code will not compile now if you pass `getResponseCode` something that does not match `ResObj` (with a `c` property which is not a number).

What if you want `c` to be maybe a number, or maybe a string? In that case, use a union type:

```
interface ResObj { c: number | string; }
```

Your original version of `getResponseCode` above will now fail to compile. TypeScript will complain that it does not know how to convert `string | number` into `number`.

If you write the code as you proposed:

```
public static getResponseCode(resObj: ResObj): number {
  if (typeof resObj.c !== "number") { return APIResponseCode.UnknownFailure; }

  let c: number = resObj.c;
  return c;
}
```

TypeScript will be happy, since its flow analysis detects the `typeof` check and knows that by the time it reaches the `return` statement `c` can only be a number.

For more complex situations, you can use what is called a type guard, which tells TypeScript explicitly that a particular function guarantees a particular type of its parameter:

```
function isNumber(c: string | number): c is number {
  return typeof c === 'number';
}
```

Now you can write

```
public static getResponseCode(resObj: ResObj): number {
  if (!isNumber(resObj.c)) { return APIResponseCode.UnknownFailure; }

  let c: number = resObj.c;
  return c;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I think I'm going to have to just stick with the `typeof` check for now since the objects I'm passing to `getResponseCode` are received at runtime and as you said, no runtime type checks occur.  Thanks again.